# Create and populate FAT32 filesystem without mounting it

Tags: filesystems, utilities, fat

Is there a way to create a FAT32 filesystem containing a set of files, without needing to mount it or have root access?

I am developing a software application for an old operating system as a hobby, and as part of the build process I would like to package up some source files into a FAT32 disk image, then launch QEMU to boot the image and run an old compiler in it.  Afterwards I would like to extract the compiled file out of the FAT32 disk image.

I can create the filesystem with `mkfs.vfat`, however the only way I know of to get files into and out of the image is to mount it, which typically requires root access and is not conducive to being embedded in a build process.

Ideally I am after something like the `zip` and `unzip` utilities, only instead of creating/extracting .zip files, it would create and extract disk images in FAT16 or FAT32 format.

Does anything like this exist?  The only things I can find online all involve mounting the disk image.

Comment: [Add files to VFAT image without mounting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22385189/995714)

Comment: Incredible stupid hack: make image with genisoimage, boot that in qemu, copy everything that should be in the fat image from the iso image to the fat image inside the qemu-booted OS. The thought process is make what you need from what you have.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Of course despite all my unsuccessful searching, I finally find the answer only moments after posting a question about it.

So the `mtools` package can do it like this:

```
# Create a 2 MB file
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1M count=2

# Put a FAT filesystem on it (use -F for FAT32, otherwise it's automatic)
mformat -i disk.img ::

# Add a file to it
mcopy -i disk.img example.txt ::

# List files
mdir -i disk.img ::

# Extract a file
mcopy -i disk.img ::/example.txt extracted.txt
```

`mtools` works by specifying drive letters (like `C:`), with the special `:` drive (specified as `::`) referring to the image given on the command line with the `-i` option.

Comment: It's also fine if you find the answer moments _before_ posting the question :D. Seriously, Stack Exchange sites are OK with posting a self-answered Q&A when you found the answer only after a lot of searching.

Comment: as a sidenote there is similar tool for F2FS called `sload.f2fs`